# Theorem? on propagating variances through function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is this a famous named theorem? Under what wider formal conditions does it hold?
It's about a random variable Y whose distribution depends on parameters $x_1,...,x_n$ when they are themselves random variables.

I have verified it to hold in a few useful cases, but did not do a general formal proof.

Let $Y = f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$

$$var (Y) =  Var (Y ! x_1=E(X_1)...x_n=E(X_n)) + \left(\frac{\partial E(Y)}{\partial x_1}\right)^2 var(x_1) + ... + \left(\frac{\partial E(Y)}{\partial x_n}\right)^2 var(x_n)$$

Clarification: all random variables X_i and X_j are assumed independent.

Backstory: this appears from a wargaming model where x1...xn are the casualties from different kinds of defensive fire, and surviving attackers (in random numbers) get to fire back. Y being the overall effect of the attackers. The game used simple Bernoulli distributions (each strength-point has a given probability of inflicting a casualty) but I thought the result is able for generalization - so this conjecture/theorem.

Comment: If n=1, I understand that one starts from a collection of random variables (Y(x)) indexed by some parameter x, then what do you call dY/dX(x) ?

Comment: Thanks for beautifying the math writing - I don't know yet enough the StackExchange's format. Clarification: I considered Y a random variable even if parameters x1...xn were constant. xk were NOT indexes, but parameters that influence the distribution of Y (and such, its average etc). It should be dE(Y)/dxk. I think my formula was right to have an independent term added for Var(Y) when parameters are constant at each of their averages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a popular simplification of the propagation of error, but it only applies to uncorrelated variables where $\sqrt{var(X_i)} \ll X_i$.

The error of the estimate of error made by this technique is analogous to the error made in using a gradient vector to approximate subsequent values of a function.

[For more information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty). This explains how this technique approximates the actual propagation of error.

Comment: Do you mean $X_i\ll E(X_i)$?

Comment: One more effort: you probably mean var$(X)\ll E(X)^2$.

Comment: Good catch, thanks ! Yes the application I devised the formula for had each xi independent of each xj. I should have spelled out the assumption. Thanks for the Wikipedia link too, with the matrix forms if there are covariances and variances as a matrix. Yes I figured out the formula is a first-order approximation and may break if the variances are large or if the transform Y differs much from linear. But I don't think Xi << E(Xi) is the proper way to express this, as E(Xi) may be zero. It's still important that the variance is small.